Screenshot of the Week #123
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 123rd edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Clockwork's screenshot from shiens-revenge won with 13 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-09-02, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-09-09, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Why is this contest ending tuesday?

@pinckerman date/timezone issue. I forgot to account for UTC


Watching the Moonfire Faire Fireworks from Limsa Lominsa in final-fantasy-xiv

Why am I hearing the Golden Saucer music in my head?


Glider Pro (1994)
glider

Wait, what? A game about folding paper plane and throwing it in a renovated room?

This is a classic. My friends and I used to play this in school all the time

Is this like The Incredible Machine?

@Joachim Hmmm, not really.  The aesthetic is similar (90’s pixel art), and there is a problem-solving aspect, but you can’t build anything in Glider.  You just fly your paper plane through the rooms in a house, navigating  the various obstacles and try to collect the clocks, power-ups, and stars.  (Playthrough)


deus-ex-mankind-divided

I love this. Great shot! Nicely abstract, cool juxtaposition. Going up into darkness, going down to the light.


A sunset in minecraft
minecraft


Rean free's his other self (ishmelga rean) from the curse. trails-into-reverie

Balcony view of the math-blaster Academy.

Not exactly spectacular but I figured it wouldn't hurt to try (especially since it's definitely not going to win any awards).


That moment where you see a boss cutscene and know you're going to get beat into the ground, Souls-like style... and the only thing you can think about is how friggin' cool it's gonna look.
astral-chain

I'm getting traumatic flashbacks from Elden Ring...
